# Dispose widget error message

Tags: qooxdoo

When I try to dispose any widget or an object - for example

`myPopupWidget.dispose()`

I have this message in my browser console:

> "000706 qx.ui.core.queue.Layout: Error in the 'Layout'
>   queue:TypeError: Cannot read property 'setStyles' of null TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'setStyles' of null".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you had a small example using the [Qooxdoo playground](http://www.qooxdoo.org/devel/playground/#Hello%20World-ria), please?

Comment: I am a very junior in qooxdoo and beg my pardon for any case. :-)
Here is the link: [playground short](http://preview.tinyurl.com/yddwq97r)
Look at the browser console. But one more time... may be I've done something stupid.

Comment: If i use `popuPP.exclude();` before dispose - it is okay.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your example, you're trying do dispose a widget attached to your root's application. So, first you have to remove this widget from it's parent and then dispose it :

```
popuPP.exclude();
//or
this.getRoot().remove(popuPP);
//then
popuPP.dispose();
```

Or you can use [destroy](http://www.qooxdoo.org/devel/api/#qx.ui.core.Widget~destroy!method_public) (it removes this widget from its parent and disposes it) :

```
popuPP.destroy();
```

Comment: Could you accept the answer if it solved your issue? Thanks